# Numpy append ones to matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've got a function that needs to add a column at the start of a given matrix. I've got it working:

```
def add_ones(X):
    return np.vstack((np.ones(X.shape[0]), X.T)).T
```

This works, but as you can see, it transposes the matrix twice. I tried it first without transposing the matrix, but it seems that `np.ones(m)` always produces a row vector that I couldn't transpose (I tried doing `np.ones(m).T)`.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? I'm not very familiar with numpy and have no idea of the performance downfalls of transposing a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate((np.ones((X.shape[0],1)),X),axis=1)
```

You can also use [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) -

```
np.column_stack((np.ones((X.shape[0])),X))
```

Final one with [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) -

```
np.hstack((np.ones((X.shape[0],1)),X))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. I didn't realise you could call np.ones with a tuple.

Comment: @Pavlin Yeah you can do that to define a 2D array with `ones` along the first axis and the second axis being a singleton, instead of a "non-tuple" case where it's defined as 1D array with ones along the only axis.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column using the c_.

`np.c_[np.ones(X.shape[0]), X]`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Comment: Think that would be `np.ones` instead and also since OP wants to prepend `ones`, so I guess - `np.c_[np.ones(X.shape[0]),X]`? Nice compact way nevertheless!

Comment: Still, that np.ones needs to be prepended I think.

Comment: Too much turkey! Fixed again.